# How to prepare encoded POST data on javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding

I need to send data by POST method.

For example, I have the string "bla&bla&bla". I tried using `encodeURI` and got "bla&bla&bla" as the result. I need to replace "&" with something correct for this example.

What kind of method should I call to prepare correct POST data?

**UPDATED:**

I need to convert only charachters which may broke POST request. Only them.

Comment: http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/

Comment: Is there no standard method to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
>>> encodeURI("bla&bla&bla")

"bla&bla&bla"

>>> encodeURIComponent("bla&bla&bla")

"bla%26bla%26bla"
```

Comment: If one is trying to mimic exactly what a browser would upload, one should note that web forms (in particular those without file attachments) use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding. In this format, browsers will encode spaces as `+` characters rather than `%20` (as is the case for `encodeURIComponent`) -- the encoding is ambiguous, but either option decodes to the same data.

[See format here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)

I would emphasize that `encodeURIComponent` is the way to go in this answer.

Comment: I must say that this solution doesn't work. ! are not encoded bu encodeeURIComponent

Comment: @Cecile Neither are `.` or `a`. Why should they?

Comment: I thought it was the reason why it failed in my case but apparently not, I just forgot the HTTP header

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `escape()` function.The `escape()` function encodes a string.
This function makes a string portable, so it can be transmitted across any network to any computer that supports ASCII characters.This function encodes special characters, with the exception of: `* @ - _ + . /`

```
var queryStr = "bla&bla&bla";
alert(queryStr);               //bla&bla&bla
alert(escape(queryStr));       //bla%26bla%26bla
```

Use `unescape()` to decode a string.

```
var newQueryStr=escape(queryStr);
alert(unescape(newQueryStr));   //bla&bla&bla
```

**Note:**

```
    escape() will not encode: @*/+

    encodeURI() will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'

    encodeURIComponent() will not encode: ~!*()'
```

After some search on internet, I got the following:

**escape()**

Don't use it.

**encodeURI()**

Use encodeURI when you want a working URL. Make this call:

```
encodeURI("http://www.google.com/a file with spaces.html")
```

to get:

```
http://www.google.com/a%20file%20with%20spaces.html
```

Don't call encodeURIComponent since it would destroy the URL and return

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fa%20file%20with%20spaces.html
```

**encodeURIComponent()**

Use encodeURIComponent when you want to encode a URL parameter.

param1 = encodeURIComponent("http://xyz.com/?a=12&b=55")

```
Then you may create the URL you need:

url = "http://domain.com/?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=99";
```

And you will get this complete URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/?param1=http%3A%2F%2Fxyz.com%2F%Ffa%3D12%26b%3D55¶m2=99
```

Note that `encodeURIComponent` does not escape the ' character. A common bug is to use it to create html attributes such as `href='MyUrl',` which could suffer an injection bug. If you are constructing html from strings, either use " instead of ' for attribute quotes, or add an extra layer of encoding (' can be encoded as %27).

REF:[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent?lq=1)

Also, as **you are using JQuery**, take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) built-in function.

Comment: Will it be more correct for POST method? I can't change code of POST receiver. I need to use URL-encoding in compliance with API.

Comment: But I don't know which method is the best for POST data:(

Comment: @Altaveron It depends on what characters you want to post. Check if your POSt contains the characters given in my answer and then use the function that encodes them.

Comment: Data may contain any character. But receiver may not decode them. Also I need to convert only charachters which may broke POST request. Only them.

Comment: @Altaveron : Stick with encodeURIComponent(). encodeURI() does not bother to encode many characters that have semantic importance in URLs (e.g. "#", "?", and "&"). escape() does not bother to encode "+" characters, which will be interpreted as encoded spaces on the server (and, as pointed out by others here, does not properly URL-encode non-ASCII characters).

Comment: @Altaveron You are using JQuery, then see last line of my answer...hope I was helpful..!!

Comment: [ESCAPE()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) is **deprecated**. Just thought to write it down in case someone wants to use it :)

Answer (score 7):

Use encodeURIComponent() as encodeURI() will not encode: `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`

This has been explained quite well at the following link:

http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Answer (score 1):

More recent DOM APIs for [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (and via [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), possibly others too) handle encoding in some cases. For example, create or use an existing URL object (like from an anchor tag) I map entries of an object as key value pairs for URL encoded params (to use for GET/POST/etc in application/x-www-form-urlencoded mimetype). Note how the emoji, ampersand and double quotes are encoded without any special handling (copied from the [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams?hl=en) devtools console):

```
var url = new URL(location.pathname, location.origin);
    Object.entries({a:1,b:"",c:'"stuff&things"'}).forEach(url.searchParams.set, url.searchParams);
    url.search;
    "?a=1&b=%F0%9F%8D%BB&c=%22stuff%26things%22"

fetch(url.pathname, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }),
    // same format as GET url search params a&b&c
    body: url.searchParams
}).then((res)=>{ console.log(res); return res }).catch((res)=>{ console.warn(res); return res; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I want POST the javascript-created hidden form.

So the question is if **encodeURIComponent()** should be used on each POST variable.

I haven't found the answer for Dmitry's (and my) question in this thread.
But I have found the answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data).

In case of form/POST where you have upload field(s) you must use `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`, if no upload field is used, you should choose yourself as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data/4073451#4073451).
Submitting the form should do the job completly, so there is no need to use `encodeURIComponent()` explicitly.

If you create a Http POST without using a form or without some library which creates a Http POST from your data, then you need choose an enctype= and join data yourselves.

This will be easy for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, where you will use `encodeURIComponent()` on each value and join them exactly as for GET request.

If you decide use `multipart/form-data` then ....? *You should google more how to encode and join them* in such case.

Comment: That's a very long winded way to say "In most cases, use the answer from three years ago, otherwise use Google".

Comment: The "no need to use encodeURIComponent() explicitly" phrase helped me

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering, there is a much easier way to do this now.
You could use `URLSearchParams[1]` class in JS ([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)).
Which accepts an `Object` parameter in the constructor.
You can then call `.toString()` on the instance to get the actual parameters, encoded using `encodeURIComponent()`

Then, in the actual request, you need to specify the `Content-Type` header to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and simply set the `body` property of the request to the `String` returned by the `params.toString()` method.

```js
const data = {"hello[World}": ``, "goodbye": ``};
const params = new URLSearchParams(data);

const endpoint = `https://example.com`;

fetch(endpoint, {
  method: `POST`,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
  },
  body: params.toString(), // hello%5BWorld%7D=%F0%9F%A5%91&goodbye=%F0%9F%98%9E
});
```