# $_POST does not pass non-alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I want to pass data via AJAX. The variable consists of both numbers and non-alphanumeric variables (`"001.0/210.00"`). My `$_POST['task']` doesn't return a value. I've attempted to change the data to JSON, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var trigger = $('.task a'),
    var container = $('#content1');
    trigger.on('click', function(e){

        var shotElement = event.currentTarget.children[0].innerText;

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'indexPipeline.php',
            data : { task: shotElement },
            success :  function(response) {                             
                $("#displayPipeline").load("indexPipeline.php");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: what does shotElement returns while loging

Comment: A slash would probably have to be escaped. Do a quick search for JavaScript escape.

Comment: and your dataType is missing use dataType:'json'

Comment: Or better yet, check out the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14830715

Comment: Where did you get from that `event`  !! Should be `e` .You should set `id` for your wanted value