# How to send a data '\n' using curl post in php?

Tags: php, post, curl

I am sending same data with PHP cURL. But I am using "\n" character in a text area and it prints **"Empty reply from server"**. Unless I use "\n", it is working.

For example:

```
<form action="gonder.php" method="post">
<textarea name="content" rows=23 cols=70></textarea>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Kaydet">
</form>
```

And my gonder.php file:

```
<?php

if($_POST['content'] != ""){

$ch = curl_init('http://address/page.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'bilgi='.$_POST['content']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

header("Location: index.php?olay=2");
}

?>
```

Additional information: My file has single-quotes at the end.

How can I solve this problem?

veriler.txt:

```
araba
ev
dükkan
mağaza
```

veriler.txt is in another server and I want to rewrite it with a textarea using post method

Comment: `$ch = curl_init('http://address/page.php);` -- this line is missing a single-quote at the end.

Comment: sory I forgot but my file have single-quote at the end

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data (`\n` is wrongly interpreted by the server)

Answer (score 0):

curl will encode for you if you pass an array, or you can use urlencode() in your existing code:

```
$content = array('bilgi' => $_POST['content']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to send the text as HTML using this functions nl2br(htmlentities()) :

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'bilgi='.nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['content'])));
```

as

```
araba<br>
ev<br>
```

Then when you receive it extract the text from html code using `str_replace( "<br>" , "\n" , $_POST['bilgi']);` , And write it into you file veriler.txt

Comment: sory I wrote wrong here. but I need '\n' because I want to write a file in other server using it

Comment: thanks but it not impact if I write 1 line, it is working but if write multiple lines, it isn't work. My problem is this already.

Comment: Give a small example for your text data.

Comment: I wrote it my main question. veriler.txt is in another server and I want to rewrite it with a textarea using post method

Comment: Yes, I think you need to send the text as HTML using this functions nl2br(htmlentities()) as 
araba<br>
ev<br>
....
Then then when you receive it extract the text and write it into veriler.txt 
as :
araba
ev