# How can I recreate this curl command in php?

Tags: php, curl, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer an api due to a lack of documentation from our software provider and I need to recreate a curl command in php.  The command in question is:

`curl -v -X POST -H Accept-Encoding:"gzip" -H deviceId:"someID" -H appBuildDate:"2014-12-11 15:56:52 +0000" -H systemName:"iPhone OS" -H appBuildNumber:"44" -H platform:"iPhone5,2" -H Content-Type:"application/xml" -H model:"iPhone" -H name:"iphone" -H systemVersion:"8.1.2" -H Authorization:"Token someToken" -H appVersion:"6.8" https://soemsub.somedomain.com/ws/orders/search -d "<orderSearch><consigneeSearch /><customerSearch /><shipperSearch scheduledArrivalEarly=\"12/17/2014\" /></orderSearch>"`

The only problem I am having is that I'm not sure what options to set for the `-d` command.

I have set `CURLOPT_POST` to `true` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` using:

```
$query = "<orderSearch><consigneeSearch /><customerSearch /><shipperSearch scheduledArrivalEarly=\"$date\" /></orderSearch>";
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
```

I have also tried:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array($query));
```

And I'm not getting valid responses.  Is there a trick to getting this to post correctly?  The command I outlined at the top is written as-is in the log file(aside from deviceId and Authorization), but I'm not sure if I can specify a post without a post "name" like I would do in an HTML form.  From what I can tell I need to have `key=>value` pairs.

Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: would help if we had a more complete view of your request instead of just a few lines

Comment: That is quite a healthy stack of headers :)

Comment: @DigitalFiz, What can I do to help you help me?  I have all the code modularized and I didn't want to post a wall of code.  Should i dump it to pastebin or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your headers without any quotes around the keys value:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization:Token someToken',
  'deviceId:someID',
  // ... all the other headers
));
```

Instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization:"Token someToken"',
  'deviceId:"someID"',
  // ... all the other headers
));
```

If you use POSTFIELDS with a string body, you need to urlencode the it:

```
$query = "<orderSearch><consigneeSearch /><customerSearch /><shipperSearch scheduledArrivalEarly=\"$date\" /></orderSearch>";
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($query));
```

See this other question: [Should I URL-encode POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data)

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data

Comment: I'm testing this now.  I think I need to specify the `Content-Type` as `"application/xml"`.  I took a look at that question you posted and I'm pretty sure I need to specify that content type.  I looked at the headers in my log files and they include it for this type of request so I think that is it!

Comment: Yeah from the examples that I see passing the string in without urlencode should be fine you probably just need to set the header.

Comment: @DuckPuncher  Sorry I thought you were also setting your headers.

Comment: @DigitalFiz I assume the headers were already being set, I've updated my answer to add them

Comment: @Ray add the Content-Type header also

Comment: @Ray, I am, just not that one.  Whoops!  Even when I set the header it doesn't seem to be working.  I'll have to toy with it a bit..

Comment: @DigitalFiz  I don't see content type being set in the original working curl request

Comment: @Ray nope ignore me :P

Comment: @Ray, it's in the original command... `curl -v -X POST -H Accept-Encoding:"gzip" -H deviceId:"someID" -H appBuildDate:"2014-12-11 15:56:52 +0000" -H systemName:"iPhone OS" -H appBuildNumber:"44" -H platform:"iPhone5,2" -H Content-Type:"application/xml" -H model:"iPhone" -H name:"iphone" -H systemVersion:"8.1.2" -H Authorization:"Token someToken" -H appVersion:"6.8" https://soemsub.somedomain.com/ws/orders/search -d "<orderSearch><consigneeSearch /><customerSearch /><shipperSearch scheduledArrivalEarly=\"12/17/2014\" /></orderSearch>"`  I had removed what I assumed was unimportant :/

Comment: @DuckPuncher ah.  You should add that to the OP. All those headers need to be added to the header array

Comment: @DuckPuncher Not positive, but you might be able to ditch the double quotes on each header string: ``'Authorization:Token someToken'``  I think command line curl needs them to demark the string, while in php it's done by the array element itself

Comment: @Ray, :D  You are my best friend right now Ray.  That was it!

Comment: @DuckPuncher Rock on.