# XMLHttpRequest POST parameter encoding

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I want to submit a POST request while passing a url among other parameters.
I have the following script but it is not working.

```
var params = "param1="+param1_value+"&url="+url_value;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", action_url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    console.log("Done");
  }
}
xhr.send(params);
```

Assuming that the `url_value` is something like this:

```
https://www.domain.com/blah?param=&amp;email=domain%40email%2Ecom&amp;blah=1234
```

what would be wrong with this script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question/answer - [Should I URL-encode POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data)

Your sample value for `url_value` is using the [HTML Entity Code](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). Because of the `&` symbol in the value, it is being sent as multiple values. You probably need to URL encode it so it looks like this

`https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fblah%3Fparam%3D%26email%3Ddomain%40email.com%26blah%3D1234`

Comment: I think the problem is something about the encoding as well, however I just encoded the url like what you suggested but nothing yet..

Comment: When you say "nothing yet" what does that mean? Is the request not going through? is your server not receiving the expected data?

Comment: I copied your code directly into my console, and as long as the `param1_value`, `url_value`, and `action_url` variables are set, it works fine for me. Can you share any errors or more information about what's wrong?

Comment: this code runs inside a google chrome extension. if the submit is successful, a cookie will be created. So, what I am looking for, is a cookie. I can not see any errors..

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem when trying to access another domain/website. The receiving side must have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its return message.

You can probably find your solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/1369528).

Comment: Assuming that the `Access-Control_Allow_Origin` does not exist, would I be able to send an html form with the same parameters to the same domain/website? Cause if I create this html form, the request is successful. The problem is on this XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Yes you can. Though I would recommend you to use jQuery, because then you can use `$('form').serialize()` to pass through `xhr.send()`. Though I think it would be better to use jQuery's `$.ajax()` function like described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotation to the url string value,alert the parameter string as below

var params = "param1='"+param1_value+"'&url='"+url_value+"'";