# getting null pointer exception on sending request data in zapier

Tags: javascript, java, zapier

Javascript code in zapier

```
 var registerData="{'uuID':'"+uuID+"','notifTitle':'"+notifTitle+"','notifBody':'"+notifBody+"','redirectUrl':'"+redirectUrl+"','notifIconUrl':'','notifyToFlag':'INDIV','source':'API'}";

   var data = JSON.stringify({"requestData":registerData});
```

In Action Class i am getting the request data

```
requestData=request.getParameter("requestData");

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(requestData);//getting exception
```

In request header

> Content-Length: 231
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> User-Agent: Zapier
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

request data which it is sending

```
{"requestData":"{'uuID':'APIKEY','notifTitle':'hiii','notifBody':'hiii','redirectUrl':'https://zapier.com/app/editor/7942969/nodes/7942970/fields','notifIconUrl':'','notifyToFlag':'INDIV','source':'API'}"}
```

console log

```
{\"requestData\":\"{'uuID':'APIKEY','notifTitle':'hiii','notifBody':'hiii','redirectUrl':'https://zapier.com/app/editor/7942969/nodes/7942970/fields','notifIconUrl':'','notifyToFlag':'INDIV','source':'API'}\"}"
```

getting Exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat java.io.StringReader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)\n\tat org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:79)\n\tat org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)\n\tat com.pushbiz.pushbizMaster.action.PushBizAction.saveAndSendNotification(PushBizAction.java:290)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat

Comment: So requestData is null, obviously. Would be helpful to know what the URL is. Typically, a URL would look something like this: `www.url.com/page?key=value&key2=value2`

Comment: Hi sir it is a post request

Comment: You're using the wrong encoding. You're saying that you send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but you're sending a JSON string instead. You need to URL-encode your post parameters rather than JSON encoding. Other the `request.getParameter` call will not be able to retrieve the parameter - it doesn't even see any parameter because the encoding format is wrong.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt He is correct. Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data?lq=1

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider What do you mean? If you agree with me you can simply upvote the comment.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I got the answer it was to stringify the data...thank youuuuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by no "requestData" param, your submitted data is a JSON object itself. I think you should change your JS to

```
var data = 'requestData':JSON.stringify(registerData);
```