# Should i encode xml and json data like query string

Tags: json, xml, post, urlencode

i have a very simple question.

whenever we post query string data by post method we url-encode it.

but now i have to post json and xml. so is that necessary to url-encode json and xml data if someone pass password value like "abc}123" or "abc<123".

thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data

Comment: its not clear according to my situation.

Comment: i just simply want to ask should i urlencode the values if i am posting json/xml

Comment: Don't think you need to do that. Your back end might require that thought. I never had to do that with json rest API's that I had worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple answer,

you do not need to encode json or xml data.